# Expected depreciation date for version 3 of Google Analytics Rest API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics currently has both Version 3 and Version 4 of REST API. Is there any expiry date for the version 3 API?

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not but [Google Analytics v2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/) is still live its an old gdata API that returns XML.  The team has not mentioned discontinuing that as far as I know.   If you are worried about them turning off V3 I wouldn't.  Even if they do you normally have a year or more before its shut down.

However I would personally encourage you to use V4.  New features will be added to V4 I am not sure how much development I would expect them to be doing on V3.

*Note: I do not work for Google but I have close contact to the Google Analytics API team.*